# Ajax Solution for Store ID

Tags: html, css, url

Ok. Maybe I worded my last post wrong, but what I'm trying to accomplish is that we have several satelite offices that are based on Geolocation for our user (e.g. if you're in the Dallas area, then Dallas will show up, etc...). the geolocation has an ID of storeID.

What I am trying to accomplish is based on whatever satelite/store office that shows, then display a certain image banner that contains a message for those users within that satelite/office region. Otherwise, if the user is NOT in that geolocation region, to display another image banner to display a message. However, I'm not quite understanding how to display a message based on the satelite/store office which is the div ID (e.g. storeID).

My initial target was if the satelite/store name showed on an html page, and that div ID contained that satelite/store name, to display a banner. My code was too long, so I am trying to streamline it based on the same concept, but also including storeData (other stuff for the store that displays on the page). I am trying to replace the original variable itemCode with customerStore and so on. Please help. This is what I have so far based on my Salesforce OCAPI layout, and can be found here - https://wbtfoundation.org:

**CSS:**

```css
#storeBanner {display:none} //banner
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="" id="storeBanner">
<a href="/store-find/" title="">
       <picture class="C-CodeClass" id="CodeClass-ID">       
         <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
          <source srcset="BANNER-DESKTOP VERSION.jpg?$staticlink$" media="(min-width: 768px)">
         <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
        <img src="BANNER-MOBILE VERSION.jpg?$staticlink$"     alt="">
      </picture>
      </a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```js
//Store ID GEO stores (OLD IDEA)
var itemCode=['Rockwall', 'Dallas', 'Richardson', 'Kentucky', 'Seattle'];
  $(itemCode).each(function(){
    if ($('#storeID').text().indexOf(this) != -1) {
     $('#storeBanner').show();
  } 
});

//Store ID GEO stores (NEW IDEA)
var customerStore = 'Store ID or Name of Store';  // Test Store
var storeOcapiUrl = '/s/athome-sfra/dw/shop/v20_4/stores/' + customerStore;

$.ajax({
   url: storeOcapiUrl,
   data: {
    client_id: 'a9392000-57a9-46a4-bd86-78c5ff617795'
},
   success: function(storeData){
   console.log(storeData);
   if ( storeData.c_enablePickup && storeData.c_enableDelivery ) {
    // show storeBanner
} else {
    // show a different storeBanner
}

} });
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly the `<div id="storeID">...</div>` contains the customer store ID value, right? If so you could create a variable at the beginning of your code and use the variable wherever needed: `let storeID = $('#storeID').text();`. If the variable should be accessible globally you may bind it to the window like `window.storeID = ...`.

Comment: Sascha. Could you please provide a sample idea, as I'm not too versed in your solution; especially for 'binding' it to the window